# How to configure and acess Remote Kernel step-by-step?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I want to access a kernel from another computer. However, I have no idea how to set up the remote kernel and how to access it. I have gone through a lot of articles on this website and others, but they confuse me more than solve my problem.

Both computers run `Mathematica 12.0` on `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` system.

Please help me out.

Comment: I would not recommend to set remote kernel at all. The best way to use Mathematica on remote computer is to use vncserver/vnc client approach. The idea is to run (on server side) vncserver (for example https://tigervnc.org/) on client machine (your ubuntu) then run either tigervnc client (or tight vnc client, https://www.tightvnc.com/, which is compatible). Of course you have tunnel the connection over ssh for safety. This is most reliable way I use many many years. If you don't need graphical interface, then a much simple alternative would be ssh to remote server and screen to run math kernel